# Positionning overflow content under fixed header and between fixed sidebars

Tags: css, position, overflow, fixed

I'm trying to design a site with a fixed header and fixed sidebars, on a 100% height body.
The only problem is I can't place the content correctly, it goes over my header.

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3FwNM/

I tried to put

```
margin:100px 0 0 0;
```

to my #content, but it push it and then a scrollbar appears on the body, I want to avoid that. Scrollbar should appear only on #content.

http://jsfiddle.net/3FwNM/2/

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Is this what you're after](http://jsfiddle.net/3FwNM/4/)? Header/content now don't overlap, but I was a bit confused by you wanting fixed sidebars. They weren't fixed in your fiddle, but I didn't know if that was just you not implementing it.

Comment: no, that's not what i'm after. AS you can see in your example, the body receives a scroll bar? i want to avoid this. The #content should not be that long, just as high as sidebars.

Comment: If the content is as hight as the sidebars, but you don't want scrollbars, alot of the text inside will overflow out of the box and not be seen. You want this? If so, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3FwNM/6/)

Comment: pretty much it. But scrollbar should be on #content, not on body. So that sidebars wouldn't scroll, only #content would scroll.

Comment: ah ok I get you. I'll post it as an answer in a sec

Comment: i'm pretty sure you'll have trouble positionning #content then, that's what make me post this thread :p waiting for your answer

Comment: you need to learn html, your html structure is totally wrong, no offence ..

Comment: I don't see much of an issue with the structure. It's not semantically accurate HTML5, but it's not *totally wrong*

Comment: @AbdulMalik : html structure is probably not perfect, but it's probably the best way to achieve the behavior I need. Any html structure of your own that would perfectly fit my needs would be greatly appreciated. So that your comment would become legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/3FwNM/8/)

One trick here is to add `box-sizing: border-box` to `#primary` and `#secondary`. This prevents the padding at the top from increasing the height beyond 100%

[Info on box-sizing property](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

EDIT: updated with vendor prefixes for `box-sizing`

Comment: 1 problem remains. There is a scrollbar on body, because its height is more than 100%.

Comment: Which link are you clicking on? Because the Fiddle I linked in my answer has no scrollbar on `body`, only on `#content`, which you wanted

Comment: I clicked on "SOLUTION" link. here is a screenshot of the fiddle, I put a green stroke around the body scrollbar : http://wir3d.net/users/david/images/dev/scrollbar.jpg

Comment: right, well in chrome it's fine. Clearly a browser issue here. Edited for vendor prefixes

Comment: Ok, it works great on every browser now. I'll now deeply read this box-sizing page you linked earlier. Thank you : )

Comment: Found a better link for box-sizing info [here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)